# Need explanation on the behavior of async file download for blobs

Tags: c#, async-await, memorystream

I have below code which runs smoothly in some cases, while in other case( mostly during debugging) it comes out with a message that "the code exited at line 0". When it happens then I change this line of code from  await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream) to  blob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream); and it start working fine.

I would like to know what wrong am I doing here, or if there is any CORRECT  way of calling this method.
As it is clear from method below , I am returning memory streams of a blob which i am reading in a new function. The below method is called by my parent method inside a foreach loop

```
public async Task<MemoryStream> DownloadBlob(string containerName, string fileName, string connectionString)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream= new MemoryStream();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
        {
            connectionString = @"UseDevelopmentStorage=true";
            containerName = "testblobs";
        }

        Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        CloudBlobClient serviceClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        if (blob.Exists())
        {
            using (memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
               
            }

        }
        return memoryStream;
    }
```

Parent method calling the above piece of code:

```
foreach (var files in res)
                    {

                        var contents = await DownloadBlob(containerName, files.DataFile.Digest.CacheName, connectionString);
                        string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(contents.ToArray());
                        lines.Add(data);
                    }
```

It will be helpful if someone can explain me this behavior of async and any good practice to avoid it.

Thanks

Comment: what does the call signature look like on the parent method? And how is the parent method being called?

Comment: Is your foreach inside another async method? Make sure it is not async void. Basically async means the main thread is released to continue running while the async method is running. For ex: var contents = await DownloadBlob(containerName, files.DataFile.Digest.CacheName, connectionString). This will not exactly run in parallel, once you are awaiting exactly at same time you call it. But your main thread will be free, so the user will not be blocked to take more actions.

Comment: You should add some try/catch instructions to your code. You might be getting some exceptions.

Comment: yes parent method is an async method too..so foreach is inside my another async method. i added try catch, but didn't receive any exception

Comment: So the parent method is async, but how is the parent method being called? Is it being called from an async method as well? Based on your description of what is happening it sounds like somewhere in your call stack you are not waiting (synchronously) or awaiting (asynchronously) the call being made and so your program is finishing before your asynchronous calls are allowed to finish.